# difference between variable definition in a Haskell source file and in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci

In a Haskell source file, I can write

```
a = 1
```

and I had the impression that I have to write the same in GHCi as

```
let a = 1
```

, for `a = 1` in GHCi gives a parse error on `=`.

Now, if I write

```
a = 1
a = 2
```

in a source file, I will get an error about Multiple declaration of `a`, but it is **OK** to write in GHCi:

```
let a = 1
let a = 2
```

Can someone help clarify the difference between the two styles?

Comment: To me, GHCi is vaguely(!) like you're in a huge `IO`-typed `do` block. Except that expressions like `1 + 2` still work. You can only use `let` to bind variables in a `do` block. A Haskell module (or "a source file") is an entirely different beast.

Comment: I get a parse error with `ghc` on the two `let` fragments you show.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I meant to two `let` gives an error in GHCi. Updated

Comment: I've always found that error oddly non-uniform; I would almost argue it should be an overlapping patterns warning rather than an error (all of the zero patterns that appear as arguments to the two defining clauses for `a` are identical!). Compare the message you get when you compile a file with `a () = 1; a () = 2`.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's a very good point... Though if you interpret them as merely overlapping patterns and leave it to be covered by the existing warning, the behaviour you'd get is that the *first* definition would win rather than the last, which is almost certainly surprising. "Never useful and usually surprising" seems worth adding a special case to make it an error, rather than "never useful but at least intuitive" as the overlapping patterns warning is.

Comment: GHCi is meant for *interactive* use. If you mistype the value of an expression would you really want to have to reset all the work you have done until that point just because you missed a `+1` instead of just redefining it and continue yur work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a key difference in Haskell in having two definitions of the same name and identical scopes, and having two definitions of the same name in nested scopes. GHCi vs modules in a file isn't really related to the underlying concept here, but those situations do lead you to encounter problems if you're not familiar with it.

A let-expression (and a let-statement in a do block) creates a *set* of bindings with the same scope, not just a single binding. For example, as an expression:

```
let a = True
    a = False
in  a
```

Or with braces and semicolons (more convenient to paste into GHCi without turning on multi-line mode):

```
let { a = True; a = False} in a
```

This will fail, whether in a module or in GHCi. There cannot be a single variable `a` that is both `True` and `False`, and there can't be two separate variables named `a` in the same scope (or it would be impossible to know which one was being referred to by the source text `a`).

The variables in a single binding set are all defined "at once"; the order they're written in is not relevant at all. You can see this because it's possible to define mututally-recursive bindings that all refer to each other, and couldn't possibly be defined one-at-a-time in any order:

```
λ let a = True : b
|     b = False : a
| in  take 10 a
[True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False]
it :: [Bool]
```

Here I've defined an infinite list of alternating `True` and `False`, and used it to come up with a finite result.

A Haskell module is a **single** scope, containing all the definitions in the file. Exactly as in a let-expression with multiple bindings, all the definitions "happen at once"<sup>1</sup>; they're only in a particular order because writing them down in a file inevitably introduces an order. So in a module this:

```
a = True
a = False
```

gives you an error, as you've seen.

In a do-block you have let-statements rather than let-expressions.<sup>2</sup> These don't have an `in` part since they just scope over the entire rest of the do-block.<sup>3</sup> GHCi commands are very like entering statements in an `IO` do-block, so you have the same option there, and that's what you're using in your example.

However your example has *two* let-bindings, not one. So there are two separate variables named `a` defined in two separate scopes.

Haskell doesn't care (almost ever) about the written order of different definitions, but it *does* care about the "nesting order" of nested scopes; the rule is that when you refer to a variable `a`, you get the inner-most definition of `a` whose scope contains the reference.<sup>4</sup>

As an aside, hiding an outer-scope name by reusing a name in an inner scope is known as **shadowing** (we say the inner definition shadows the outer one). It's a useful general programming term to know, since the concept comes up in many languages.

So it's not that the rules about when you can define a name twice are different in GHCi vs a module, its just that the different context makes different things easier.

If you want to put a bunch of definitions in a module, the easy thing to do is make them all top-level definitions, which all have the same scope (the whole module) and so you get an error if you use the same name twice. You have to work a bit more to nest the definitions.

In GHCi you're entering commands one-at-a-time, and it's more work to use multi-line commands or braces-and-semicolon style, so the easy thing when you want to enter several definitions is to use several let statements, and so you end up shadowing earlier definitions if you reuse names.<sup>5</sup> You have to more deliberately try to actually enter multiple names in the same scope.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or more accurately the bindings "just are" without any notion of "the time at which they happen" at all.

<sup>2</sup> Or rather: you have let-statements as well as let-expressions, since statements are mostly made up of expressions and a let-expression is always valid as an expression.

<sup>3</sup> You can see this as a general rule that later statements in a do-block are conceptually nested inside all earlier statements, since that's what they mean when you translate them to monadic operations; indeed let-statements are actually translated to let-expressions with the rest of the do-block inside the `in` part.

<sup>4</sup> It's not ambiguous like two variables with the same name in the same scope would be, though it is impossible to refer to any further-out definitions.

<sup>5</sup> And note that anything you've previously defined referring to the name before the shadowing will still behave *exactly* as it did before, referring to the previous name. This includes functions that return the value of the variable. It's easiest to understand shadowing as introducing a *different* variable that happens to have the same name as an earlier one, rather than trying to understand it as actually changing what the earlier variable name refers to.

Comment: Your first sentence pretty much says it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Successive `let` "statements" in the interactive interpreter are really the equivalent of nested `let` expressions. They behave as if there is an implied `in` following the assignment, and the rest of the interpreter session comprises the body of the `let`. That is

```
>>> let a = 1
>>> let a = 1
>>> print a
```

is the same as

```
let a = 1 in
let a = 1 in
print a
```